# in django import error occurred as module not found

Tags: python, django

I was doing simple form handling.My project name is 'mysite' and i created the folder 'books' using startapp.I made one folder called 'templates' inside 'mysite' folder.Inside 'templates', i made one html file of search form and its name is 'search_file.html'.
The code to made that html file is written below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, i wrote the following code in views.py which is located inside 'books' folder.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search_form.html')
```

After that i wrote code in urls.py which is located in 'mysite' folder as below.

```
from mysite.books import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),

)
```

My file tree is shown below:

The main folder is 'mysite' and within this:

```
- books

    - __init__.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
    - tests.py
    - views.py

- mysite

    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py

- templates

    - search_form.html

- manage.py
```

But, when i run in browser then the error appeared mentioning these things.

ImportError at /search-form/

No module named books

What is the solution for this error?

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace, please?

Comment: Sorry i am just a beginner so i didnt know what does stacktrace means.Could you explain please?

Comment: Ya i have mentioned the error of import error at search_form .The error is 'No module found named books'.

Answer (score 2):

**The best solution would be to just move your "books" package inside mysite/mysite/ and add books to your settings.INSTALLED_APPS**

But if you want to keep it like that then:

Your main "mysite" folder is not a python package. This means you need to add **init**.py in the main folder, see bellow:

You should have:

```
mysite/
    books/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py

    templates/
        search_form.html

    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py      
    manage.py
```

Edit `manage.py` and replace `mysite.settings` with `settings`

Edit `settings.py` and replace `ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'` with `ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'` and `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'` with `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'`

Add `<path to>/templates` to your settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS

Add `books` to your INSTALLED_APPS

Edit `wsgi.py` and replace `mysite.settings` with `settings`

Now you should be able to do from `books import views`

Also as you can see, you can then remove mysite/mysite folder

Comment: I did all the things that you told me to do but still the same error occurred.Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Updated my response. Let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score 1):

After 8 Years i had the same Problem :D

The Solution from Ciprian Tarta worked for me.
But i only needed to change "mysite.settings" to "settings" in the manage.py file

I used Django version 3.2.9 and Python version 3.9.9

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a file called `__init__.py` in your folder books ?

Comment: Yes, I have already created __init__.py folder inside the folder 'books'.

Comment: You're getting a circular import error. Your outer folder is called `mysite` and where you have your settings is called `mysite`, rename your `mysite` where your settings live to something else, and I believe it should work

Comment: But i havent named mysite folder inside the project mysite.When i started mysite project, it automatically made mysite folder inside mysite project.

Comment: when i rename the folder 'mysite'  into 'site' which is inside the project folder 'mysite'and when i tried to start server using python manage.py runserver,lots of error appeared.So, can you give another solution?